# How to search for APT packages with a specific substring in their names only?

Tags: apt, synaptic, aptitude

In the past I used to search for a package specifying a part of its name in Synaptic, as far as I can remember. Now it searches in package descriptions too and this is very inconvenient as it gives a huge lot of irrelevant results. I have tried using console aptitude and `apt-cache search` but both of them do the same. So how do I search in the names only (ignoring the descriptions)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `apt-cache`, you can use the `--names-only` switch with your search term, and/or use some regex to narrow the searches down. Some examples I have used are listed below.

1) Using `--names-only` with a simple search of the word launcher cuts out a lot of results:

```
apt-cache search launcher --names-only
```

Often when using regex in your searches, `--names-only` isn't necessary as well, since you narrow the results down much further anyway, as these examples below demonstrate.

2) You could use regex to find all available desktop environments available:

```
apt-cache search -- '-desktop$'
```

3) or to find dev files that you don't know the name of:

```
apt-cache search 'jpeg*-dev'
```

The methods shown in the examples above are very useful when using `apt-cache` to search for packages for which you only partially know the name.

Comment: Both `apt-cache search launcher --names-only` and `apt-cache search --names-only launcher` work! I thought the first one wouldn't.